# How to install python3-PyWavelets

Tags: python, pip

I would like to install a package for wavelet analysis in python and could just find this one here.
https://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/

It seems that this package is not part of Ubuntu repositories, is there a way to add it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just download the library manually and stick it in your Phython's lib folder. I've done it in the past with things that weren't in the repos. I forget which folder exactly so if you're not sure if you have it in the right place, just open a Python terminal and try to import it. If it's not the right place it'll fail. I'm on mobile right now, so if somebody doesn't beat me to it, this evening I'll try to get on my PC and see what directory works and then edit this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find because python3-PyWavelets is python package.

Run `pip install PyWavelets`

If you are getting error pip not found, then

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

To install with conda

```
conda install pywavelets
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that a similar package is available through the Ubuntu repositories which is called python3-pywt

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I found the package:

```
apt-cache search python |grep -i wavelet
```

This will list, among other results:

```
python3-pywt - Python3 extension implementing of wavelet transformations
```

Now get more detailed info about it:

```
apt-cache show python3-pywt
```

The output confirms that this package is the one you want, so install it:

```
sudo apt install python3-pywt
```